# Publishing Error while cleaning wildfly server and redeploying a web app

Tags: jsp, servlets, wildfly-9, jboss-developer-studio

I'm working on a simple web project using Jsp Servlet technologies with WildFly 9 Server , when I make some changes to the project (modifying the code of the servlets ,or the code of jsp pages ) and  I try to clean the server in order to apply the changes and redeploy the web application I get the next error "Publishing to WildFly 9 has enountered a problem " .....as below 
Could someone help me to solve this and Thks

[image]

Comment: Check the permissions on `C:\Tools\ServerZip\wildfly-9.0.1.Final`. It looks like you're user doesn't have permissions to the directory or possibly do the deployment.

Comment: I had already  changed the permission of the curent user but the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of C:\Tools against those of your C:\Users\username. You can use the Windows cacls tool to do that. I had the same problem when working with my C:\work directory and since I got back to my home directory those errors disappeared